# Insert two values in SXA custom search query token (ResolveSearchQueryTokensProcessor)

Tags: sxa, search-facet

I am working with a custom SXA search query token. I want to `Insert` with two different values.

```
foreach (var val in values)
  {
     args.Models.Insert(i, this.BuildModel(itemFieldName, val));
  }
args.Models.Remove(model);
```

**SearchStringModel:**

```
protected virtual SearchStringModel BuildModel(string fieldName, string value)
{
  var name = fieldName;
  return new SearchStringModel("custom", FormattableString.Invariant(FormattableStringFactory.Create("{0}|{1}", name, value)))
  {
    Operation = "must"
  };
}
```

But this logic is not showing search results. Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Did you check the search logs to verify the query that was performed?

Comment: @Gatogordo yes query is being executed, shown in the logs. When one value is inserted, search results are working but not with the two.

Comment: And is the query correct with 2 values? You can verify this query with your solr/azure search if needed to see what is wrong. And if not correct, share what is actually wrong with it.

Comment: @Gatogordo this is the search query: `?q=(itemid_sm:(ea15966f4e8e494384a9f210cd94d273) AND itemid_sm:(1646be1cb09d473fab86ebc9b7e5e668))`, as you can see its putting the AND operator instead of OR between the values. How can I put OR instead of AND?

Answer (score 0):

The AND or OR operators in between the parts of your query are placed based on the `Operation` as set in the `SearchStringModel`.

In your case, the Operation is set to "**must**" - which is an AND. If you want an OR, you can use "**should**" here:

```
protected virtual SearchStringModel BuildModel(string fieldName, string value)
{
  var name = fieldName;
  return new SearchStringModel("custom", FormattableString.Invariant(FormattableStringFactory.Create("{0}|{1}", name, value)))
  {
    Operation = "should"
  };
}
```

Comment: If should is added as operation, then it changes the overall query. should operation query: `(_template:(36206e5352f74164ad95e6c18f35dd53) OR itemid_sm:(ea15966f4e8e494384a9f210cd94d273) OR itemid_sm:(1646be1cb09d473fab86ebc9b7e5e660))`. must operation query: `(_template:(36206e5352f74164ad95e6c18f35dd53) AND (itemid_sm:(ea15966f4e8e494384a9f210cd94d273) AND itemid_sm:(1646be1cb09d473fab86ebc9b7e5e660)))`. Desired query: `(_template:(36206e5352f74164ad95e6c18f35dd53) AND (itemid_sm:(ea15966f4e8e494384a9f210cd94d273) OR itemid_sm:(1646be1cb09d473fab86ebc9b7e5e660)))`

Comment: Can you share the query with you token that you used?

Comment: Query: `template:{1646BE1C-B09D-473F-AB86-EBC9B7E5E111};sxa:ItemsWithSameFieldValue|UserFieldName|ItemFieldName`. I have also tried `+template:{1646BE1C-B09D-473F-AB86-EBC9B7E5E111};sxa:ItemsWithSameFieldValue|UserFieldName|ItemFieldName`. OR operator is needed between the values inserted by this token.

Comment: I think the "+" (also) needs to be in front of the sxa:ItemsWithSameFieldValue.. (not sure, can't test this myself now)